# How to create a transparent Button with JavaFX without decreasing the hitbox?

Tags: css, user-interface, button, javafx-8, transparent

As soon as I create a new Button in JavaFX and set the background transparent with: `myButton.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);` or `myButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;")`,
the hitbox will only consist of the text in the button when catching the ActionEvent via :

```
myButton.setOnAction(newjavafx.event.EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        //handle UI input
    }
});
```

So I have to aim on a letter and click it, which is annoying, especially when having changing text and/ or small text.

How can I keep my hitbox the same while having a transparent background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
myButton.setPickOnBounds(true);
```

which means that the layout bounds of the button will be used to determine mouse hits on it, rather than its set of non-transparent pixels.

Comment: Doesn't do any change for me.

Comment: @openGLisLife Can you create a simple [MCVE] in the question, so I can test?

Comment: You were right. Without this modification on my scene: myScene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); it works fine. Thank you!